# How to apply Bootstrap styles to a Flask template table?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm just starting with Flask and Bootstrap and am confused as to how to apply Bootstrap styles to a table that Python inserts in my template.

The normal html is:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
 {{ table }}
</body>
```

I use flask_table to populate with my data as follows:

```py
results=db.search(gsearch.name != "") #Search of tinyurl database
 mytable=ResultTable(results) #put into columns
 return render_template('index.html', form=search, table=mytable)
```

and the ResultTable class is then:

```py
class ResultTable(Table):
    guestid = Col ('ID', show=False) #unique identifier for each entry
    name = LinkCol('Name', 'edit', url_kwargs=dict(id='guestid'),attr='name') #clicking on this edits that entry
    email = Col('Email') #email address for each entry
```

So I had thought I'd do something like:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
  {{ table }}
</table>
```

But that doesn't work at all...

Any hints would be really appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us some of your python code, what is `table` exactly ? Are you using `flask_table` ?

Comment: thanks - I've now done that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the [flask table documention](https://flask-table.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#table-configuration-and-options), you can add classes to the `table` dom by adding them to the `classes` attribute of the `Table` python object.

In your case, it would be something like this :

```
class ResultTable(Table):
    classes = ['table', 'table-striped', 'table-bordered', 'table-condensed']
    guestid = Col ('ID', show=False) #unique identifier for each entry
    name = LinkCol('Name', 'edit', url_kwargs=dict(id='guestid'),attr='name') #clicking on this 
    email = Col('Email') #email address for each entry
```

Comment: Thanks - that's really helpful (although I feel a bit stupid).